# Non-serializable object error while working on Memcache

Tags: java, nosql, memcached

Hi everyone i was working with memcache, and when i compiled this code i got following errors.

```
2010-07-09 10:35:53.499 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=localhost/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2010-07-09 10:35:53.520 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@7fdcde
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-serializable object
 at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.serialize(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:86)
 at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder.encode(SerializingTranscoder.java:135)
 at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.asyncStore(MemcachedClient.java:301)
 at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.set(MemcachedClient.java:691)
 at def.Tweet.main(Tweet.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: def.User
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1173)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:343)
 at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.serialize(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:81)
 ... 4 more
```

I managed to fix it with converting User class toString but ı dont want to use toString method.I just want to use my class to add and get mwethods. How can i fix this problem?
Here is the code i am using.

```
package def;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient;

public class Tweet {
  private static User user;
  private static Message message;
  private static Followers follower;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 try{
     user = new User(1,"Mehmet Özer","asd","127.0.0.1","True","Onine");
  //String deneme = user.toString();
  MemcachedClient c=new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 11211));


  // Store a value (async) for one hour

  c.set(user.userKey, 3600, user);
  System.out.println(c.get(user.userKey));

    }
  catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Sorry , i forgot the User class, I am also giving you the User class to help me better.

```
public class User {
    public static String userKey = "UserDB";
    public static int userID ;
    public static String userName;
    public static String password;
    public static String ipAddress;
    public static String isOnline;
    public static String lastActive;

    public User(int userID, String userName, String password, String ipAddress,String isOnline,String lastActive)
    {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.isOnline = isOnline;
        this.lastActive = lastActive;

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(this.userID);
        System.out.println(this.userName);
        System.out.println(this.password);
        System.out.println(this.ipAddress);
        System.out.println(this.isOnline);
        System.out.println(this.lastActive);

        return super.toString();
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Memcache doesn't know how to serialize your objects. You'll need to implement `Serializable` to have Java handle the serialization, or `Externalizable` if you need more control over the (de)serialization process.

Comment: What do i have to implement in serializable method exactly ?

Comment: You need to implement the `Serializable` interface: `public class User implements Serializable { }`. The interface is just a marker that tells the serialization mechanism that the `User` class can be serialized. The actual serialization is done automatically, so you don't have to implement any methods.

Comment: Furthermore, the reason applying toString() worked in the first place is because String is Serializable, i.e. it can be converted to bytecode and back again.

Comment: @Niels you should edit your answer (from your comment).

Answer (score 3):

Updated due to question modification.

So, your User class must implements the [Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Hopefully, this is as simple as writing

```
 public class User implements Serializable {
 ...
 }
```

as Serializable does not contains any method.

Comment: Sorry for missin class.I added the User class as you said.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is coming because, JVM is not able to serialized object corrctly because of conflict in schema. In my case,  Serial version ID of some classes are defined 1L as default. These classes are corporately to each others. I assigned some unique custom value. My Problem resolved.